# addEventListener on Panel

Tags: google-app-maker

I have a use-case where I need to programmatically add/remove the onClick event associated with a panel.

I have tried the following solution but receive a `cijCell.addEventListener is not a function` error.

```
function cij_enabled(){
  var cijCell = app.pages.Home.descendants.cellFour;
  var index = cijCell.styles.indexOf('disabled-card');

  if (Report.riskOfLoss === 'High') {
    cijCell.styles.splice(index, 1);
    cijCell.addEventListener("click", function() {
      app.popups.Customer.visible = true;      
    });
  } else {
    if (index === -1){
      cijCell.styles.push('disabled-card'); 
      cijCell.removeEventListener("click", function() {
      app.popups.Customer.visible = true;      
    });
    }
  }
}
```

How can I achieve the desired outcome? Is adding eventlisteners possible in this fashion through app maker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely do so and you got it almost right. The only thing you need to understand is that the appmaker widget is not a native html element hence the error:

> cijCell.addEventListener is not a function

Fortunately, AppMaker has a way of getting the native html elements associated to a widget. You need to use the `getElement()` method and then you can use the add/remove event listeners methods. So you should change your code from `cijCell.addEventListener...` to `cijCell.getElement().addEventListener...`

Reference: https://developers.google.com/appmaker/scripting/api/widgets#Panel